# How to install extensions on Chromium without the web store?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, xorg, google-chrome-extensions

I tried to install the Reddit Enhancement Suit, when Chromium complained that I can only install extensions easily from Web Store. It downloaded the .crx file. How can I apply it? The [linked help page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning) says:

> Steps on adding extensions from other websites
>
> We recommend you only add extensions from other websites that you trust. In Chrome, you can follow these steps to add the extension:
>
> - Download the extension file from the website and save it to your computer.
> - Click the wrench icon on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Tools > Extensions.
> - Locate the extension file on your computer and **drag the file** onto the Extensions page.
> - Review the list of permissions in the dialog that appears. If you would like to proceed, click Install.

I'm running `chromium` in X and have no idea how I'm supposed to drag from `xterm`.

Comment: Related for chrome: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063331/how-to-install-google-chrome-extensions-though-terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it works:

- Open a file manager in X (for example in KDE, open dolphin).
- Go to the location of the downloaded CRX file (Downloads folder?).
- Click on the downloaded CRX file and drag it into a window of Chromium.

This process should install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with mailvelope extension I wated to try in Chromium on Debian.

Solution was:
`CHROMIUM_FLAGS='--enable-remote-extensions'` in `/etc/environment` (relogin then…)
or just start Chromium on CLI with: `CHROMIUM_FLAGS='--enable-remote-extensions' chromium`.

Afterwards I was allowed to install with the link from the project website withour any further issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

- download the crx
- then change the file extension to zip
- unzip it
- go to chrome://extensions
- enable developer mode
- upload unpacked extension
- select your folder